# How is the memory allocation done by malloc and calloc function in C?

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

> malloc() allocates a single block of memory whereas calloc() allocates
> multiple blocks of memory, each block with the same size.

How do they differ from each other in internal implementation?

I tried the below code and tried to figure out the difference between the internal implementation of malloc and calloc (considering the above-quoted text).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int *p=(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   p[0]=3;
   p[1]=4;
   printf("%d\t%d",p[0],p[1]);
   free(p);
   int *q=(int*)calloc(2,sizeof(int));
   q[0]=1;
   q[1]=2;
   printf("\n%d\t%d",q[0],q[1]);
   free(q);
   return 0;
}
```

But I didn't find any difference(from the output) between these two functions.
What change should I do to understand the internal implementation of both functions?
Here my meaning to the internal implementation is mentioned in the above-quoted text.

I hope you got my question.

Thanks

Comment: The quote is a difference in the API definition and not necessarily the internal implementation - malloc accepts bytes as a size whereas calloc accepts number of elements and element size in bytes. In fact it is highly likely that any implementation would be largely be the same for both except a small part to deal with the size and memory zeroing of `calloc`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no big difference with the internal implementation perspective of both, or on most implementations `calloc` does use `malloc` followed by `memset` to zero the memory allocated as shown below example snippet. Refer to [calloc](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.33/source/malloc/malloc.c#L3571) implementation.

```
void *calloc(size_t n, size_t elem_size)
{
    const size_t nbytes = n * elem_size;
    void *p = malloc(nbytes);
    if (p != NULL) {
       memset(p, 0, nbytes);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: is the memory allocation done by malloc or calloc similar to an array(created by static memory allocation)?

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal, malloc/calloc is dynamic gets allocated at runtime and array static allocation is static at program compile time.